# Selenium says form textbox Element is read-only - but it is not

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I had this working previously, but something changed and I wanted to move it to a different vm anyway. The page does not appear to have changed. fields are still `L1` and `P1`. There are no popups or whatever.

The error I get is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: Element is read-only: <input id="L1" class="LoginFormData" name="L1" type="text">
```

- Debian Stretch
- Python 2.7.13
- Selenium v3.141.0
- Geckdriver v0.24.0

Code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://testsite.org/")
username = driver.find_element_by_name("L1")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("test user")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("P1")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("logmein")
driver.find_element_by_id("login").click()
driver.get("https://testsite.org/Overview.aspx")
driver.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
driver.close()
display.stop()
```

This is the path and csspath:

```
//*[@id="L1"]
#L1
html body.BodyHome form#frm center table tbody tr td.PageBody div#divPageDetail.PageDetail table tbody tr td.Blank table tbody tr td.IntroLeft table tbody tr td.Blank div.IntroHeaderLogin table tbody tr td.LoginFormData input#L1.LoginFormData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to work around this by adding the following line. I would like to know if there is a better way. Thanks

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("L1")[0].removeAttribute("readonly")')
```